# Sticky Footer Trouble

Tags: html, sticky-footer

Can anyone tell me why this page...
http://dev.wokingdancefestival.co.uk/mailingList.php
...is not receiving a sticky footer. I am at the hair pulling stage with this so any help would be fully appreciated.

I have marked all the sections in borders so you can see what is what.

Thanks

Comment: `<div id="inner_container">` and `<div class="push">` are not inside `<div id="container">`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

follow **exactly** this div structure and css... and it will work: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: That is what the mark-up is based on. I exchanged the 4em part for pixels as otherwise the footer was not high enough.